# How to detect if voice over is on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, maps, voiceover

What is the equivalent to UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning(); 
in xamarin forms ? 
I am trying to hide a map if voice over is detected. is this possible? 
or is there any way to hide any readable context that comes in the maps
so far, I tried AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="false" but the reader still identify items in the map that confuses the user.

workaround -> 
on ios --

```
 public bool IsVoiceOver()
        {
            var a =  UIAccessibility.IsVoiceOverRunning;
            if (!a) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("voice over is : " + a);
                return false;
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("voice over is : " + a);
            return true;
            }
        }
```

on forms - >

```
 public interface IVoiceOver
    {

        bool IsVoiceOver();


    }
```

on the project ->

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                ShowingUser = true;
                var a = Check.IsVoiceOver();
                if(a == true) 
                {
                    DisplayMap=false;
                }
```

Comment: Custom renderers needed there is no direct way

Comment: do you have any example I could see

Comment: Nothing that i have handy currently but yes you can easily find it if you just search the keywords in your preferred search engine

Comment: I did that already. nothing helpful. thanks anyway

Comment: No don't look for xamarin forms look for native ios and android and then convert that code to a custom renderer

Comment: As G.hakim's said , this need native method to do in ios and android.Here is officail doc to use CustomRenderer.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers)

Comment: Thanks! I did a dependency service I updated my question.